# How to build LLVM using GCC 4 on Windows?

Tags: c++, mingw, llvm

I have been able to build LLVM 2.6 (the llvm-2.6.tar.gz package) using MinGW GCC 3.4.5. I haven't tested properly, but it seems to work.

The trouble is, I have libraries of my own which don't build using GCC3, but which work fine in GCC4 (template issues). I believe the first official GCC4 version for MinGW is GCC 4.4.0.

*EDIT*

Decluttered - everything useful in the "tried this tried that" info is now in the answer.

*EDIT*

Most of this question/answer is redundant with LLVM 2.7 - the standard configure, make routine works fine in MinGW with no hacks or workarounds.

Comment: I've accepted my own answer for the moment and I'm moving on to using the library, but I may return and add an answer for building using llvm-gcc and some other stuff at some point, when I figure it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If at first you don't succeed...

I can now build LLVM 2.6 using MinGW GCC 4.4.0, and it isn't too hard once you know how. I still cannot run the DejaGNU tests, though at first sight that shouldn't be that hard - most likely I'll need the CygWin packages for dejagnu and expect. I also haven't built llvm-gcc yet.

Before the step-by-step, here are the three problems...

---

Problem 1...

Attempting to build llvm using the standard build instructions fails with the
following compiler error in Signals.cpp (win32/Program.inc)

```
llvm[1]: Compiling Signals.cpp for Release build
In file included from Signals.cpp:33:
Win32/Signals.inc: In function 'LONG LLVMUnhandledExceptionFilter(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS*)':
Win32/Signals.inc:234: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
```

The workaround is to use "make -k -fexceptions" - answer found in the pure language documentation.

---

Problem 2...

Even with the first workaround, the following compiler error occurs...

```
ExternalFunctions.cpp: In function 'bool ffiInvoke(void (*)(), llvm::Function*, const std::vector<llvm::GenericValue, std::allocator<llvm::GenericValue> >&, const llvm::TargetData*, llvm::GenericValue&)':
ExternalFunctions.cpp:207: error: 'alloca' was not declared in this scope
```

It seems that an option is being specified which disables the "alloca" built-in.

The workaround is to edit the problem file

```
C:\llvm-2.6\lib\ExecutionEngine\Interpreter\ExternalFunctions.cpp
```

Just after the "#include <string>" line, insert...

```
#define alloca __builtin_alloca
```

---

Problem 3...

Even with the compilation errors fixed, the example programs won't run. The run-time errors are...

```
Assertion failed: errorcode == 0, file RWMutex.cpp, line 87
```

This relates to the use of the pthreads library, in the following lines of
RWMutex.cpp

```
86:   // Initialize the rwlock
87:   errorcode = pthread_rwlock_init(rwlock, &attr);
88:   assert(errorcode == 0);
```

The basic issue is that pthreads support is included in MinGW GCC, and included in the builds of AFAICT all the GCC4 variants - including the unofficial TDM builds, as well as including MinGW GCC 4.4.0. This was *not* included with MinGW GCC 3.4.5, which is why LLVM builds fine with default options on that compiler. Using 4.4.0, the LLVM configure script detects the pthreads support and uses it - but the pthreads-w32 library used seems not to be fully compatible.

One workaround is to delete the following files from mingw gcc 4.4.0 as suggested in http://markmail.org/message/d7zw2zjq7svevsci - yes, I know I previously said they weren't there, but I had my folder layout confused...

- mingw32\include\pthread.h
- mingw32\include\sched.h
- mingw32\include\semaphore.h
- mingw32\lib\libpthread.a

It is better, though, to simply tell the configure script to disable threads...

```
./configure --disable-threads
```

---

So, the steps are...

First, install the following MinGW and MSYS packages...

- binutils-2.20-1-mingw32-bin.tar.gz

  mingwrt-3.17-mingw32-dev.tar.gz

  mingwrt-3.17-mingw32-dll.tar.gz

  w32api-3.14-mingw32-dev.tar.gz

  gcc-full-4.4.0-mingw32-bin-2.tar.lzma

  make-3.81-20090914-mingw32-bin.tar.gz

  tcltk-8.4.1-1.exe

  MSYS-1.0.11.exe

  msysDTK-1.0.1.exe

  bash-3.1.17-2-msys-1.0.11-bin.tar.lzma

  bison-2.4.1-1-msys-1.0.11-bin.tar.lzma

  flex-2.5.35-1-msys-1.0.11-bin.tar.lzma

  libregex-0.12-1-msys-1.0.11-dll-0.tar.lzma

This package list may be more than needed - in particular tcl tk is only needed for the DejaGNU tests, which I haven't got working yet.

Make sure that the \bin folder of your MinGW install is on the PATH (Control Panel, System, Advanced, Environment Variables).

Extract llvm-2.6.tar.gz

Edit the file C:\llvm-2.6\lib\ExecutionEngine\Interpreter\ExternalFunctions.cpp, and just after the line "#include <string>", add the line

```
#define alloca __builtin_alloca
```

Start an MSYS command prompt, and run...

```
cd /c/llvm-2.6
./configure --disable-threads
make -k CXXFLAGS=-fexceptions
```

I'm assuming you extracted llvm to c:\llvm-2.6

Handy hint - try "./configure --help"

Consider the --enable-targets=host-only and --enable-doxygen configure script options in particular.